# Parsing through a list to find a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers and I want to check if a definite sequence exists in that list. For example, for `[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6]` how can I determine if the sequence 3-4-5 exists?

I tried using nested loops, but ran into a problem with break/continue. I am now reducing the list to its unique elements and seeing if my sequence exists:

```
ls = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6]

uniq_ls = []

for item in ls:
    if item not in uniql:
        uniq_ls.append(item)


for ii, item in enumerate(uniq_ls):
    if item == 3:
        if uniq_ls[ii+1] == 4:
            if uniq_ls[ii+2] == 5:
                print('yes, sequence exists')
```

Above method works, but I want to do this without reducing the original list to its unique elements.
How can I do this?
As pointed out by some folks, this method will work only if the original list is sorted.
It will not work for a list like [1,1,1,3,2,2,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,3,2,1]
I need it to work for a unsorted list like this one.

Comment: Is the list going to be in sorted order? Can sequence be 3,3,4,4,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,.... to detect 3-4-5?

Comment: Is the list always going to be sorted? Also, do you care about multiple instances of the same number? If not, just use a set instead of a list.

Comment: I don't understand the step with the unique elements. Would `3,4,5` _not_ be in `3,1,2,3,4,5,6` because the `3` would only count when it first occurs?

Comment: you guys are correct. I was apparently completely off track on this one. Yes the list will not always be sorted. So my unique list approach is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function:

```
def f(lst, seq):
    for n in range(len(lst)-len(seq)+1):
        if lst[n:n+len(seq)] == seq:
            return True
    return False
            
print(f([1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6], [3,4,5]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

---

You can also turn that into a one-liner:

```
def f(lst, seq):
    return any(lst[n:n+len(seq)] == seq for n in range(len(lst)-len(seq)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution to this when the list is unsorted. I am not sure if this is the most elegant, pythonic way -

List L1 is [1,1,1,3,2,2,4,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,3,2,1]

I will have an empty list L2 = [] and add first item of list to it.

Then I will append L2 with item from L1 if previous item is not the same as current item

So L2 eventually should look like [1,3,2,4,3,4,5,3,2,1]
From this list it will be easy to find a sequence 3-4-5.

New code:

```
l1 = [1,3,2,4,3,4,5,3,2,1]
l_uni = []

for ii, item in enumerate(l1):
    if ii==0:
        l_uni.append(item)
    elif l1[ii] != l1[ii-1]:
        l_uni.append(item)


for jj in range(0,len(l_uni)):
    try:
        if l_uni[jj]  == 3:
            if l_uni[jj+1] == 4:
                if l_uni[jj+2] == 5:
                    print('found sequence')
                    break
    except IndexError:
        print('no sequence')
```